# Split value according to shares in other table

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0849c8e777c8c19a419670dd08cd4d2d)**

```
CREATE TABLE costs (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    event_date DATE,
    country VARCHAR,
    channel VARCHAR,
    costs_per_day_per_country DECIMAL);

INSERT INTO costs
(event_date, country, channel, costs_per_day_per_country)
VALUES 
('2020-02-08', 'DE', 'channel_01', '400'),
('2020-02-08', 'DE', 'channel_02', '400'),
('2020-02-08', 'FR', 'channel_01', '400'),
('2020-02-08', 'FR', 'channel_02', '400'),
('2020-02-08', 'NL', 'channel_01', '400'),
('2020-02-08', 'NL', 'channel_02', '400'),

('2020-04-15', 'DE', 'channel_01', '300'),
('2020-04-15', 'DE', 'channel_02', '300'),
('2020-04-15', 'FR', 'channel_01', '300'),
('2020-04-15', 'FR', 'channel_02', '300'),
('2020-04-15', 'NL', 'channel_01', '300'),
('2020-04-15', 'NL', 'channel_02', '300');


CREATE TABLE revenue (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    event_date DATE,
    country VARCHAR,
    revenue_share DECIMAL);

INSERT INTO revenue
(event_date, country, revenue_share)
VALUES 
('2020-02-08', 'DE', '0.60'),
('2020-02-08', 'FR', '0.30'),
('2020-02-08', 'NL', '0.10'),

('2020-04-15', 'DE', '0.60'),
('2020-04-15', 'FR', '0.30'),
('2020-04-15', 'NL', '0.10');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
event_date    |    country   |     channel       |            costs              |
--------------|--------------|-------------------|-------------------------------|---------
2020-02-08    |      DE      |     channel_01    |      120  (=400 x 0.6 / 2)    | 
2020-02-08    |      DE      |     channel_02    |      120  (=400 x 0.6 / 2)    |   
2020-02-08    |      FR      |     channel_01    |       60  (=400 x 0.3 / 2)    |   
2020-02-08    |      FR      |     channel_02    |       60  (=400 x 0.3 / 2)    |   
2020-02-08    |      NL      |     channel_01    |       20  (=400 x 0.1 / 2)    |   
2020-02-08    |      NL      |     channel_02    |       20  (=400 x 0.1 / 2)    |  
--------------|--------------|-------------------|-------------------------------|---------
2020-04-15    |      DE      |     channel_01    |       90  (=300 x 0.6 / 2)    |   
2020-04-15    |      DE      |     channel_02    |       90  (=300 x 0.6 / 2)    |   
2020-04-15    |      FR      |     channel_01    |       45  (=300 x 0.3 / 2)    |   
2020-04-15    |      FR      |     channel_02    |       45  (=300 x 0.3 / 2)    |   
2020-04-15    |      NL      |     channel_01    |       15  (=300 x 0.1 / 2)    |   
2020-04-15    |      NL      |     channel_02    |       15  (=300 x 0.1 / 2)    |
```

---

In the first table I have `costs_per_day_per_country`. 
Now, I want to split those costs according to the `revenue_share` in the second table to each country. 
Addtionally, the allocated costs should be split equally to each channel.

I tried to go with this query:

```
SELECT 
c.event_date, 
c.country, 
c.channel,

  /* Allocate the costs_per_day_per_country according to the revenue share */
  (CASE WHEN c.country IN ('DE') THEN MAX(c.costs_per_day_per_country) * MAX(t1.revenue_share)
        WHEN c.country IN ('FR') THEN MAX(c.costs_per_day_per_country) * MAX(t1.revenue_share)
        WHEN c.country IN ('NL') THEN MAX(c.costs_per_day_per_country) * MAX(t1.revenue_share)
  END) 
  
  /* Split the allocated costs equally to each channel */
  * (1.0 / COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.event_date, c.country)) AS costs_allocated
  
FROM costs c
LEFT JOIN

  (SELECT 
  r.event_date, 
  r.country, 
  r.revenue_share
  FROM revenue r
  GROUP BY 1,2,3
  ORDER BY 1,2,3) t1 ON t1.event_date = c.event_date

GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

It almost gives me the expected result but it somehow does not apply the `revenue_share` correctly to each country. 
It applies the 0.6 to every country.

How do I need to modify the query to get the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct the solution is far simple than the query you implemented, all you need to do is to join the two tables and use a `COUNT() over (PARTITION BY)` appropriately to count the channels

```
SELECT 
c.event_date, 
c.country, 
c.channel,
(costs_per_day_per_country * revenue_share)/COUNT(c.channel) over (partition by c.event_date, c.country) dt

FROM costs c
LEFT JOIN
 revenue t1 ON t1.event_date = c.event_date and t1.country=c.country

ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```